# Save 2D histogram as heatmap in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, histogram, heatmap

I'm trying to plot 2D histogram as heat map.

Here is the code:

```
def save_2d_hist(hist2D):
    import pylab as pl
    print hist2D.shape

    pl.pcolor(hist2D)
    pl.colorbar()
    pl.savefig('graph.png')
```

My hist is (11L, 10L) but the picture that I get have 12 rows, how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy option would be:

```
pl.pcolor(hist2D)
pl.colorbar()
pl.xlim([0,hist2D.shape[1]])
pl.ylim([0,hist2D.shape[0]])
pl.savefig('graph.png')
```

[image]

If you don't like that solution, you may want to use `imshow` instead of `pcolor`

```
pl.imshow(hist2D, interpolation='none')
pl.colorbar()
pl.savefig('graph.png')
```